How to remove a child node in xslt but only for a value-of element?
I have an xml doc like this :
<doc>
 <article>
  <photo>
   <caption>
    <p>
     caption text<credit>photo copyright</credit>
    </p>
   </caption>
  </photo>
 </article>
</doc>


As you can see the "credit" tag is nested in the "p" tag…
I have an xsl code like this :
<xsl:template match="/doc">
   <caption>
       <xsl:for-each select="article/photo">
           <xsl:value-of select="caption/p"/>
           <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
           <xsl:value-of select="caption/p/credit"/>
       </xsl:for-each>
   </caption>
</xsl:template>

So I have an output like this :
<caption>
    caption text photo copyright
    photo copyright
</caption>

What I would need is just removing the nested "credit" tag, and its content, but only for my first value-of element, as I need to keep it for my second value-of. So I would get this output :
<caption>
    caption text
    photo copyright
</caption>

Which would be better as I don't want the photo copyright to be repeated… but I do need a line break between caption text and photo copyright…

You could change <xsl:value-of select="caption/p"/> to <xsl:value-of select="caption/p/text()"/>.

In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153).

Couldn't you do simply:
<xsl:template match="/doc">
   <caption>
       <xsl:for-each select="article/photo/caption/p//text()">
           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
           <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
       </xsl:for-each>
   </caption>
</xsl:template>


This was the right way to do it, many thx ! Siebe Jongebloed's answer is even more accurate I think, but yours was almost the same anyway.

<xsl:value-of select="caption/p"/> will use all (descendant) text of that selected node().
To only select the direct text-node of p use that one in your select, like this: caption/p/text()
In your example it would look like this:
  <xsl:template match="/doc">
    <caption>
      <xsl:for-each select="article/photo">
        <xsl:value-of select="caption/p/text()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="caption/p/credit"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </caption>
  </xsl:template>

And to skip the redundant caption/p do this:
  <xsl:template match="/doc">
    <caption>
      <xsl:for-each select="article/photo/caption/p">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="credit"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </caption>
  </xsl:template>

